# How to open site with ngork?

Tags: localhost, tunnel, ngrok

I have just started using ngork recently and so basically I run the below command:

```
ngork http 8080
```

Well now I get the following in the terminal:

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                       (Ctrl+C to quit)

Tunnel Status                 online
Version                       2.0.25/2.0.25
Region                        United States (us)
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://7c0de733.ngrok.io -> localhost:8080
Forwarding                    https://7c0de733.ngrok.io -> localhost:8080

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Now when I open the following link:

```
http://7c0de733.ngrok.io/ , This link opens up `http://7c0de733.ngrok.io/xampp/`, now what I really want to see is my wordpress demo website and so I type in the following:

http://7c0de733.ngrok.io/wordpress/ , but I get nothing.
```

How do I open my WordPress site now, and why is it not opening with the above link?

Answer (score -2):

try doing this.
ngrok http [port] -host-header="localhost:[port]"
It will work :)